# Sql Order By Value

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-order-by

How can I order by a **Select** by a sequence?

I mean, I have these datas:

```
column_1   |   column_2
    1      |      a    
    2      |      b    
    3      |      c    
    4      |      d
    4      |      e    
    3      |      f    
    1      |      g    
    2      |      h
```

And I want to order by 1-4 group, I mean:

```
column_1   |   column_2
    1      |      a    
    2      |      b    
    3      |      c    
    4      |      d
    1      |      g    
    2      |      h 
    3      |      f    
    4      |      e
```

I would like column_1 ordered by **1,2,3,4** sequence of values then **1,2,3,4** again. 

I mean, **I don't want** ordering this way: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4...

**[[EDIT]]** 
The column_2 should by Asc, I mean: **Order By column_2 Asc**

**[[EDIT 2]]** 
I will use this Select on SQLite. I'm trying to find a way using just SQL commons commands.

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ad449)

Does anyone know how it's possible?

Comment: Is there anything to know which 2 should come after a specific 1?  Or does that matter?

Comment: Yes, Order By **column_2 Asc**

Comment: if you want 1,1,2,2 then `group by`. If you also want ordering then `group by col_1, col_2 order by col_1, col_2 asc`

Comment: I don't want 1,1,2,2. I want: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by a sequence, you really want to *enumerate* each value in column 1, independently for each value.  For example:

```
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
4     2
3     2
2     2
1     2
5     1
5     2
5     3
```

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this in SQLite.  In MySQL, you would use variables.  In other databases, window functions.  You can accomplish this correlated subqueries:

```
select column_1, column_2
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.column_1 = t.column_1 and t2.rowid <= t.rowid
             ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
order by seqnum, column_1;
```